# Evento "click" en filas añadidas a google maps Place Autocomplete no funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, google-api, autocompletar, google-places

estoy usando la **API** de **google Place Autocomplete** para buscar ciudades en un input y he utilizado **jquery autocomplete** para poder hacer un búsqueda en mi base de datos y sacar los hoteles que tengo guardados en ella.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podeis ver, los hoteles tienen el icono de una casa.

El caso es que he conseguido realizar esa búsqueda conjunta pero al hacer click en uno de los hoteles, no hace nada. Desaparece el desplegable y no hay manera de recoger el evento click. En cambio si hago click en alguno de los destinos que el autocomplete de google, funciona correctamente.
Os dejo mi código aquí:

HTML:

```
<input id="accommodation-name" type="text" class="textfield form-control" placeholder="Indica un destino, alojamiento…" />
```

Jquery Autocomplete:

```
$("#accommodation-name").autocomplete({
        delay: 300,
        source: "url/to/ajax/autocomplete",
        response: function( event, ui ) { // cada vez que se escribe una letra
            // Elimino los valores antes de insertas los nuevos
            $(".pac-container #areasearch").each(function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
            // Inserto los nuevos valores
            for (var i = 0; i < ui.content.length; i++) {
                if(ui.content[i].type == "acom"){
                    var inner_html = '<div id="areasearch" class="pac-item" onclick="setAccommodation(\''+ui.content[i].title+'\')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span><span class="pac-item-query"><b>'+ui.content[i].title+'</b></span> <span>'+ui.content[i].town+'</span></div>';
                    $(".pac-container").prepend(inner_html);        
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Google Place Autocomplete:

```
function initialize() {
         var options = {
          types: ['geocode'],
          componentRestrictions: {country: "es"}
         };
        var input = document.getElementById('accommodation-name');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);options);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Tengo creada una función llamada setAccommodation(), que no se ejecuta pese a ponerlo en el atributo "onclick":

```
function setAccommodation(name){
    console.log(name);
    $("#accommodation-name").val(name);
}
```

Y un evento click:

```
$("pac-container div").click(function(){
    alert(123);
});
```

Con todo esto, al hacer click en uno de los alojamientos que he metido en el listado "pac-container", no pasa absolutamente nada. Se cierra el autocomplete y ni se ejecuta la función ni el evento click.

Para terminar os dejo un ejemplo de los datos que recibo al hacer la llamada ajax que tengo en mi controller, la que recibe los alojamientos:

```
[
    {
        "type":"acom",
        "id":3,
        "title":"Don Claudio",
        "town":"Bilbao, Bizkaia",
        "lat":"43.27779",
        "long":"-2.97325",
        "url":"pensiondonclaudio",
        "category":"Alojamiento",
    },
    {
        "type":"acom",
        "id":20,
        "title":"Udondo",
        "town":"Derio, Bizkaia",
        "lat":"43.2921316",
        "long":"-2.888667899999973",
        "url":"hostal-udondo",
        "category":"Alojamiento",
    }
]
```

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, te recomiendo que la solución la pongas como una respuesta a la pregunta, no editando la pregunta original!

Answer (score 0):

**Solución**

Al final era mas fácil de lo que parecía: Bastaba con cambiar el atributo onclick="setAccommodation(\''+ui.content[i].title+'\')" por onmousedown="setAccommodation(\''+ui.content[i].title+'\')", ya que de esta manera, onmousedown se ejecuta antes que el script de google cierre el desplegable donde se encuentran los resultados.